# Cross Domain Trickery With Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to develop a live stats widget and am running into some cross domain issues. How do I get around these?

The function to insert the hit works fine, data is recorded into the database etc.  When I try to retrieve the data I receive the following error in firebug:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://wplivestats.com/stats/stats.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

```
 (function($) {
    $('#stats').css({
        'clear': 'both',
        'display': 'block',
        'width': '60px',
        'height': '20px',
        'background': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #45484d 0%,#000000 100%)',
        'text-align': 'center',
        'font-family': 'Arial',
        'font-weight': '900',
        'color': '#ffffff',
        'padding': '5px',
        'border-radius': '3px',
        'border': '1px solid #fff'
    });

    var cref = document.referrer;
    var curl = document.URL;
    $.post('http://wplivestats.com/stats/stats.php', {ref:cref, url:curl}, function(data) {
        /*optional stuff to do after success */
    });

    function updateStats() {
    $.get('http://wplivestats.com/stats/getstats.php', function(data) {
     $('#stats').html(data);    
    });

    }

    var myVar=setInterval(function () {updateStats();}, 5000);

    })( jQuery );
```

Comment: did you even read the error message? "... or enabling CORS"...

Comment: Proxy the call from a server side call? Or if they allow JSONP, use that.

Comment: If you don't have control over that server from which you're attempting to fetch some content, then you'll have to implement a server-side proxy to do it.

Comment: Thanks pointy and marcb, a little server tweak and I'm good to go